# how to solve curl error 60:ssl certificate problenm in youtube data api V3?

Tags: php, ssl, curl, guzzle, youtube-data-api

I am learning to work with youtube data api v3 (using PHP). So I downloaded sample api code and some how i manage to download and install composer in my working directory(version 1.4.x) successfully.

Ater this i run the serach.php script it shows following error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException' with message 'cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)' in C:\wamp\www\youtube feeds\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 187
>   ( ! ) GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException: cURL error 60: SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate (see http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) in C:\wamp\www\youtube feeds\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Handler\CurlFactory.php on line 187 .

I am using wamp with php 5.5.12 and apache 2.4.9. Also I enabled curl extension from tray and in php.ini file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is due to a missing "cacert.pem" file (or provided by the host operating system that runs php). This file verifies certificate authorities, so that curl can connect to youtube securely (and know it's youtube, and not a victim of a man in the middle attack).

You cna download these files manually, and specify them in your php ini, but the better option is to use the "certainty" php package to manage these. I would advise using composer, it's very easy to start using.

Answer (score 1):

If just starting out, do not try to jump into the deep end.
Start with the "restfull" api side of things.

As an example, you can do this.

```
$url_link = 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet&id=[VIDEO_ID]&key=[API_KEY]';

$video = file_get_contents($url_link);
$data= json_decode($video, true);
```

Then you can grab the required info in that call as you like. Like this

```
$vid = $data['id'];
```

LIB's are good for streamlining large programs and code, but not always needed.